# How to set interface implementation in generic interface?

Tags: c#

I would like to write generic interface

```
interface IFoo<TYPE>{}
```

But also I would like to restrict this `TYPE` like this (for example)

```
interface IFoo<TYPE: MyAnotherClass>{}
```

So, it is means that I don't want that user will pass any `TYPE` that don't implement `MyAnotherClass`

How to achieve this behavior in C#?

**P.S.** In Java(for example) it is possible...

Comment: here [is the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) for the duplicate I need a little more time, can't believe that it is so difficult to find the right one. unbelievable... :)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski finally thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface IFoo<T> where T : MyAnotherClass {
}
```